# Changing a JList from another runnable Application

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am currently trying to change the elements of `JList` from another class. I like to separate the GUI from the working app.

In this example I have a GUI with just a `JScrollPane` and a `JButton`. And I have an app. which is a runnable Class and if I press the button it should set runnable as true and there should be some elements added. However I cannot solve how to link these 2 classes in such a way that the GUI refreshes and shows the elements immediately.

### Code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestGUI {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    private TestApi testApi;
    private JButton button = new JButton();

    private DefaultListModel<Person> personDefaultListModel = new DefaultListModel<Person>();
    private JList<Person> personJList = new JList<>(personDefaultListModel);

    public TestGUI () {

        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setTitle("TestGUI");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addPerson(new Person("Fresh","Prince"));

        panel.add(personJList);
        scrollPane.createVerticalScrollBar();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startAdding();
            }
        });
        button.setText("press me");

        frame.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        testApi = new TestApi(panel);
    }

    private void addPerson (Person p){
        personDefaultListModel.addElement(p);
    }

    private void startAdding(){
        this.testApi.setRunning(true);
    }

    public static void main (String... args){
        new TestGUI();
    }
}
```

### The app:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestApi implements Runnable{

    private boolean running = false;
    private DefaultListModel<Person> personDefaultListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Person> personJList = new JList<>(personDefaultListModel);
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public TestApi (JPanel panel){
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (running){

            addElements();
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(personJList);
            setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    private void addElements(){

        addPerson(new Person("Margot","Hinterseer"));
        addPerson(new Person("bla", "blubb"));

    }

    private void addPerson (Person p){
        personDefaultListModel.addElement(p);
    }
}
```

### And finally the person:

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + surname;
    }
}
```

Would be fine if you could help me there.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `while (true)` loop? It really doesn't make much sense. If this were my code, I would not pass any Swing component such as panel to the other class, but instead would give the GUI public methods that allow outside classes to mutate its state. Either that or have the GUI listen to state changes in a separate model object in a model-view-controller set up.

Comment: Note that the `run()` method is never called, nor is a Thread created, the Runnable inserted, and thread started, and so run will never, *run*. Probably a good thing, but again, please tell me just what you're trying to accomplish with that while loop.

Comment: as far as i know is the run() with the boolean another way to launch the application. because i will need to get this same process with like an textfield where i am searching for content and the jlist will print all of the results. and therefor i will have listeners to keys so i automatically will search. i think there i can do sth different, but the problem is, that even if i call run() in my actionPerformed() it doesnt do the job

Comment: i tried the public version, but i dont have a instance to name, i tried to give the jlist in the constructor but then i just change it in the app.

Comment: Thank you for the updated information, but please [edit] your question and add even more clear and specific information in your question about what you want the other application to do. Note that if you call `run()` you will lock the Swing GUI with that `while (true)` loop. And no, the `run()` with the boolean is not "another way to launch the application".

Comment: If you want the outside class to add a person, make the `public void addPerson (Person p){` method ***public***, and call that method. If you want it to swap to a different list model, then give your class a public method for this.

Comment: `"... but i dont have a instance to name"` -- ??

Comment: thanks a lot hovercraft, you gave me a good hint there to solve it. i rewrite the code and give the run() a parameter (just made a function in my app to do it)

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, one way to allow outside classes to mutate a class is to give the class a public method that outside classes can call, and then passing an instance of the key instance of this class to where it is needed. For instance, consider changing

```
private void addPerson (Person p){
    personDefaultListModel.addElement(p);
}
```

to public.

```
public void addPerson (Person p){
    personDefaultListModel.addElement(p);
}
```

If you need to change the list's complete model, then give this class a public method that allows you to do this:

```
public void setListModel (DefaultListModel<Person> model){
    personJList.setModel(model);
}
```

Other problems with your code:

- a `while (true)` loop called on the Swing event thread will freeze your application and so has no place here.

For instance, say you wanted to launch a dialog window that allows another class to add a Person to the main GUI JList, you could do:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainPersonGui extends JPanel {
    private DefaultListModel<Person> personDefaultListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Person> personJList = new JList<>(personDefaultListModel);
    private JDialog addPersonDialog;

    public MainPersonGui() {
        personJList.setVisibleRowCount(15);
        personJList.setPrototypeCellValue(
                new Person("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        addPerson(new Person("Duck", "Donald"));

        JButton addPersonBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Person") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (addPersonDialog == null) {
                    Window owner = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MainPersonGui.this);
                    addPersonDialog = new JDialog(owner, "Add Person", ModalityType.MODELESS);
                    addPersonDialog.add(new AddPersonPanel(MainPersonGui.this));
                    addPersonDialog.pack();
                }
                addPersonDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(personJList));
        add(addPersonBtn, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    // !! make this public
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        personDefaultListModel.addElement(p);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainPersonGui mainPanel = new MainPersonGui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class AddPersonPanel extends JPanel {
    private MainPersonGui personGui;
    private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField lastNameField = new JTextField(10);

    public AddPersonPanel(MainPersonGui personGui) {
        this.personGui = personGui; // set the reference to main

        add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
        add(firstNameField);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
        add(lastNameField);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Insert Name") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String name = firstNameField.getText();
                String surname = lastNameField.getText();
                Person person = new Person(name, surname);

                // **** here call the main's addPerson() method ****
                personGui.addPerson(person);
                firstNameField.setText("");
                lastNameField.setText("");
            }
        }));
    }
}
```